# Is it possible to discover unused memory regions with GDB?

Tags: gcc, gdb

I am trying to reduce a programs memory usage, and an example I just manually found was an array that would allocate 150 elements, but only the first 3 elements were actually used.

I was wondering if there is a way that GDB could analyze which memory regions are allocated but then never actually read from during program execution, to help me find other similar cases. The program is in C so GCC flags are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to discover the actually unused memory you will need support by a hardware debugger that capture at least a write access to memory.

GDB has no built in hardware support so it can't discover it. But you can try to detect the changed memory. For this purpose you can allocate the memory with a pattern before the (program/functions/snippet/what ever) is executed and check where the data pattern is modified. This can be used e.g. for detection of the maximum used stack size. After testing your program you can examine the filled memory area and when you see the first mismatch you have a good guess.

Warning! This method doesn't detect all memory modifications. The program could write that data pattern that you used to mark as "unused memory". So choosing a good pattern can help. Using a pattern "all zero" is weak, because filling a memory with zeros in the program is probable. But a sequence of 0xdeadbeaf might be more sensible.